# ignoring additional arguments after filling up an array java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

**The code:**

```
//takes in the parameters by int and string and builds an array
public void setParameter(int newParameterNum, String newParameterName) {

    this.parameterNum = newParameterNum;

    this.parameterName = newParameterName;

    this.parameterList = new String[numParameters];

    this.parameterList[parameterNum] = parameterName;

    for (int i = 0; i < numParameters; i++) {

         this.countParameter += i;
    }


}
```

**The main code(cannot be edited):**

```
//Add the needed parameters, Report should make sure I am not trying to break it
    report1.setParameter(0, "01/01/1970");
    report1.setParameter(1, "01/01/2018");
    report1.setParameter(2, "pjdt");
```

**The error:**

> ```
> run: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2   at
> ```
>
> week6project.Report.setParameter(Report.java:134)     at
>   week6project.Week6Project.main(Week6Project.java:34)
>   C:\Users\nicho\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

So, how do I go about ignoring the parameters I do not want to add to the array? If the requested amount of parameters is less than the parameters passed.

i.e it asks for `2 parameters` but `3` are passed in this case.

```
The numParameters is updated through this method:
public void setNumParameters(int newNumParameters) {

    this.numParameters = newNumParameters;

}
```

**The main method that sets:**

```
 //Set the number of parameters for each report
    report1.setNumParameters(2);
    report2.setNumParameters(4);
```

Comment: You need to update `numParamters` before you initialize the `Array`

Comment: I don't want to add the parameters that the user is not requesting even if they put in more than requested.

Comment: make sure that `0 < parameterNum < numParameters`

Comment: so that got rid of my error using a if statement but now it only prints out null? would that be an issue with my print statement? when i index through printing each one?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Sounds like this question is dealt with and you now have a new problem, so please post a new question at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you try to access an array element with `index>= array.length`.

in the following line of code, make sure that `0 <= parameterNum < numParameters`

```
this.parameterList[parameterNum] = parameterName;
```